# Why isn't a simple sieve proof of Bertrand's Postulate?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I wish to show a prime in $(n,2n)$. I make a list of numbers $n+1$ through $2n-1$.

I check $n+1$ for prime factors $p_i<\sqrt{2n}$. It has a factor of $p_1$. I cross off numbers $\equiv n+1 \pmod {p_1}$.

I check $n+2$, it has $p_2$, I cross off remaining numbers $\equiv n+2 \pmod{ p_2}$. And so on, you know how sieves work.

There are only $\pi(\sqrt{2n})$ factors I have to rule out before I get a prime. Even in the naive absolute worst-case totally impossible scenario of running into a Jacobsthal $h(n)$ run of small factors and using the conservative upper bound for that, I think that *still* comes out to a prime popping out before $2n$, although I'll admit I haven't checked carefully, because I would hope you could rule that out anyway.

I know this is not a proof, but it seems like it could be without much work if the principle is sound; that said, the principle seems so obvious that I'm sure I'm missing something.

What am I missing?

Comment: You admit that the sieve is no proof, but you ask why it is not a proof ? I am confused. Goldbach's conjecture also is "obvious" but even the best evidence is no proof. In the case of Betrand's postulate , it is only "obvious" for large $n$. I think the evidence for Goldbach is much better although it has not been proven.

Comment: I'm saying that it appears to me that this could easily be a proof, but assume I am mistaken, and asking why it could not easily be made a proof.

Comment: The real upper bound of a prime gap almost surely is much smaller than the proven upper bound. For large $p$ , the proven bound exceeds $\sqrt{p}$ , while $\ln^2(p)$ is probably enough.But as long we do not have a proof, we cannot rule out gaps that are much much larger then expected. A more extreme example : It would be insane if there were only finite many NON-Wieferich-primes. But we cannot rule it out !

Comment: How would you generalize it?   So does $p_n + 2$ have any prime factors for the $n$th prime in general?  How the @&!\$ would I know?

Comment: I once thought it as obvious that if you had $p_1,.....,p_k$ then $p_k + p_{k-1}$ is obviously not divisible $p_k$ and $p_{k-1}$ and then $p_k + p_{k-1}-p_{k-2}$ wouldn't be be divisible by $p_k, p_{k-1}, p_{k-2}$ but obviously we can have $p_c|p_a \pm p_b$ so that doesn't follow  I thought somehow that because $p_{k}$ and $p_{k-1}$ would be relatively close that that wouldnt be an issue and that finding a manipulation of $p_1,...,,p_k$ to find a number between $p_k... 2p_k$ that is not divisible by $p_1,..., p_k$ still *feels* like it should be possible... well, "The devil is in the details".

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing, is induction on $n$. Just because it works for one value of $n$, does not prove it for all other values of $n$. Proving any finite number of cases, doesn't always prove things for all $n$. That's why cover sets, and induction are so important. $n+1$ induction is a cover set for the natural numbers starting with a base case of 0 or 1. Any complete residue system for a given modulus form a trivial covering set, of the integers .  All primes except the prime factors of a modulus, are covered by the equivalence classes forming the modular multiplicative group.